# NON-BREAKING HYPHEN in Word interop C# Range

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-interop, non-breaking-characters

Please help. 
I have a code. The code searches  `@"<(3)[-^~]([1-4])[-^~]([1-4])[-^~]([0-9]{1;3})?([0-9]{2})>" //(strings like 3-2-1-123-15 )` and puts the hyperlinks on it. But imagine, if the

> 3-2-1-123-15

has NON-BREAKING HYPHEN between numbers. If I put range to text (`string s = rng.Text;`)(I need it because I am using the same string in my hyperlink: r`ngFound.Range.Hyperlinks.Add(rngFound.Range, hyperlink + rngFound.Text));` then I will have:

> 32112315

situation. But how can I have string with "-". I mean how can I replace NON-BREAKING HYPHEN with "-". Do I need to replace it in the word text?(It is not very good). And if I do then how can I do that using function:

```
Word.Selection FindAndReplace2(Word.Selection rngToSearch, object findText, object replaceWithText) //Find function
        {
            bool found = false;
            //options
            object matchCase = false;
            object matchWholeWord = true;
            object matchWildCards = true;
            object matchSoundsLike = false;
            object matchAllWordForms = false;
            object forward = true;
            object format = false;
            object matchKashida = false;
            object matchDiacritics = false;
            object matchAlefHamza = false;
            object matchControl = false;
            object read_only = false;
            object visible = true;
            object replace = true;
            object wrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindStop; ;

            //execute find and replace
            found = rngToSearch.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
                ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundsLike, ref matchAllWordForms, ref forward, ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText, ref replace,
                ref matchKashida, ref matchDiacritics, ref matchAlefHamza, ref matchControl);
            if (!found)
            {
                rngToSearch = null;
            }

            return rngToSearch;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol for a non-breaking hyphen is ANSI 31: `¬`. This can be included in the search string, as illustrated below

```
(<(3)[-^~¬]([1-4])[-^~¬]([1-4])[-^~¬]([0-9]{1;3})?([0-9]{2})>
```

My tests found both the original string in the question, as well as one where `¬` replaced the `-`.

Once `Find` is successful, the `Range` object contains the text that was searched. It should be no problem to assign that to a `string` and perform `Replace` on the string, only (so that it doesn't affect the text in the document, only the string used to create the hyperlink). Something like this (untested):

```
string foundNr = rngToSearch.Text;
string hyperlinkNr = foundNr.Replace("¬", "-");
```

Comment: Yes thanks. I did it like this:  `Word.Selection rngFound = FindAndReplace(app.Selection, searchTerm2, ""); //searching and wrapping.
                    string foundNr = rngFound.Text;
                    string hyperlinkNr = foundNr.Replace((char)30, (char)45);`

Comment: @VladyZautin `((char)30)` or `((char)31)` ? I'll edit it into the answer once you've confirmed...

Comment: Right now `((char)30) `worked for me. It is same as `ctr + Shift + "-"  `in Word.